# Folder is not being included in AEM package

Tags: aem, crx

I am trying to make a package of a specific folder "/content/diagnostics/states" to migrate it to a different instance of AEM.  but it's not being included when I try to build the package, the package manager is just giving me an empty "/content/diagnostics" folder.  Any idea of whats going on?

See screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, all the nodes were there in a hidden .content.xml file